# To install GNU Cut in OSX?

Tags: homebrew

I did not find it in brew by `brew search cut`. 
I wound if it exists in any other package systems.

How can you install GNU Cut in OSX?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`cut` is part of [CoreUtils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html).

To install it :

```
brew install coreutils
```

Then it's available in terminal as `gcut`.

Comment: How is then GNU cut presented in my system? By gcut? I do not want replace BSD commands.

Comment: It won't replace the BSD commands. As you guessed, it will be accessible with gcut (if you have set the `$path` to work with brew packages).

Comment: What do we need to do to set the path correctly? Could you please add to your answer? I haven't found a beginner-friendly step-by-step for installing `coreutils` on OS X (and even more difficult to find, a guide with El Capitan in mind). Do you have any references for that?